# Is there a way to avoid the "redeclared function" fatal error while defining functions within functions in PHP?

Tags: php, fatal-error

I've been implementing a certain plugin (dtabs) on my page in Wordpress but after upgrading to the latest version, I found that I now have an error the 2nd time I call the main function called `dtab_list_tabs()`.

The way it works is, the plugin gets include_once'd but the main function is called however many times you want to place tabs in your layout. I have 2 such calls to `dtab_list_tabs()`.

Now, the problem is, for whatever reason the developer decided to include another function directly inside `dtab_list_tabs()` called `current_tab()`. Because it's declared within a function, apparently PHP tries to redeclare it as soon as you call the parent function the 2nd time, which doesn't make any sense to me.

> PHP Fatal error:  **Cannot redeclare current_tab()** (previously declared in .../wp-content/plugins/dtabs/dtabs.php:1638) in .../wp-content/plugins/dtabs/dtabs.php on line 1638

The code for that revision is at http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/!svn/bc/208481/dtabs/trunk/dtabs.php

**What I'm trying to figure out is whether there is a way to tell PHP that yeah... it has an internal function, which is a perfectly valid PHP paradigm as far as I know, so don't redeclare it and fail.**

As for the situation at hand, I have removed `current_tab()` as it doesn't appear to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [function_exists()](http://docs.php.net/function_exists) to test if a function with that name has already been defined. If you make the definition conditional ( if(something) { function foo() {...} } ) php will "evaluate" the definition only when the condition is met.

```
function foo() {
  if ( !function_exists('bar') ) {
    function bar() {
      echo 'bar ';
    }
  }

  bar();
}

foo();
foo();
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/functions.user-defined

(But I'd try to avoid such things all together)

Comment: Right, but this solution involves modifying the plugin code which I don't necessarily have access to. I'm trying to see if there is a way to tell PHP not to fail like this from outside of the function that declares a sub-function. Guess not, unless someone finds a way.

Comment: @Artem Russakovskii: In that case, send an email to the developer and hit him on the head. A fatal error is a fatal error and there is no way of getting around a fatal error. It is fatal for a reason... I have yet to see anyone avoid death.

Comment: Heh, actually, you should check out ErrorException http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php - it seems to be the way to turn fatal errors among other things into Exceptions, and then catch them.

Comment: I doubt you can prevent php from bailing out on a fatal error using ErrorException.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your function declaration in an `if` statement. Use [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/function_exists) to see if the function has been previously declared or not.

```
if(!function_exists('current_tab')) {
  function current_tab() {
    myMagicCode();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if (!function_exists('my_function')) {
  function my_function() {

  }
}
```

> [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/function_exists) - Return TRUE if the given function has been defined